# How to substitute 80% of a string with "underscore" ( " _ " ) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I have a string as stated in my code. I want to remove 80% of the string letters and replace them with " _ " (underscore).

I have managed to replace all the string chars with " _ " but I can't make it replace only 80% of my string.

```
var a = "mystring";
var splitted = a.split('');

var count = 0;
while(count < a.length) {
    if(splitted[count] !== '_' && splitted[count] !== ' ') {
        splitted[count] = '_ ';
        count++;
    } 
 }

console.log(splitted);
```

Code Output : _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
Desired Output: _ y _ _ _ _ _ _
or :  _ _ s _ _ _ _ _
or :  _ _ _ _ _ _ i _

Comment: not seeing 80 or 0,8 in your code. what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Comment: actually the expected result is a replacement for the 87.5% of your string: what should happen for words of length 9 or 10 ?

Comment: actually 80% means 4 out of 5 chars. So, for each 5 chars, underscore 4 characters and display 1 that maybe first or last.

Comment: I believe you should calculate how many symbols are this 80% for each string and use it in the char-replace-loop not to exceed this number when converting into underscores ;)

Comment: I have replaced 100% of my string with " _ ". That is what I am asking. I want to replace 80% of my String with " _"

Comment: do you like to remplace the first 80% or the last  , or random letters ? @KlevisXhyra

Comment: if(count%5 == 0) -> display the char else display "_". Thats it.

Comment: lets say random letters

Comment: Also, the increment (`count++`) should be outside the `if`.

Comment: @KlevisXhyra you should really look at the padLeft and padRight

Comment: @Haroldo_OK I will surely will. As soon as finish with this. Thanks. Very grateful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
        return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
    }

    var a = "mystring";
    var len = a.length;
    var x = len * 0.8;
    var ceil= Math.ceil(x);
    var i;
    var used = [];

    for (i = 0; i < ceil; i++) {
        var exist = true;
        while (exist) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
            exist = used.includes(index);
        }
        a = a.replaceAt(index, '_');
        used.push(index);
    }
 console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to  remplace 80% of your string ,your need to search all length  of the word and then multiply by 0.8 then  do while  to remplace  a random  letter.

```js
     var string = 'mystring';
        var splitted = string.split('');
        var percent = Math.round(splitted.length * 0.8);
        var changues =0;

        while (changues<percent){
            var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * splitted.length ) + 0);
            if(splitted[random]!='_'){
                splitted[random]='_';
                changues++;
            }

        }
        string=splitted.join('');
        console.log(string);
```

Comment: This solved my question as I wanted. All other answers are appreciated. They also work. Thanks you Stack Overflow Community.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest **simple** solution I can come up with. It will hide letters with certain probability. Let's say you want to hide letters with "80% probability", then it's done like this. Of course it won't hide 80% of letters every time:

```js
const hideLetters = (str = '', probability = 1, mask = '_') => {
  return str
    .split('')
    .map((letter, i) => (Math.random() >= probability) ? letter : mask)
    .join('');
}

console.log(hideLetters('mystring', 0.8));
console.log(hideLetters('password', 0.5, '*'));
```

Comment: you could combine the pattern `str.split('').map(cb)` to `Array.from(str, cb))`, because strings are spreadable because of the implemented `Symbol.iterator`.

Comment: If you want to be sure it replaces 80% of characters, you could first build an array (better yet, a `Set()`) of random, non-repeated positions to replace, with 80% of the size of the string, and then use that to do the replacements. Or maybe first build an array of sequential positions, delete 20% of them, then use it to know which positions to replace on the String.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace a single character by checking a random value.

```js
var string = "mystring",
    replaced = string.replace(/./g, c => Math.random() < 0.8 ? '_' : c);
    
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: This approach gives any character a probability of 80% to be replaced, so this could result on all character replaced, or with a very low probability, none character replaced. It is an elegant approach, however I think the OP wants the `80%` of the characters to be replaced and leaves the rest without change

Answer (score 0):

You could first replace all letters and then calculate numbers of letters to return back to original.

```js
function replace(string, percent) {
  let re = string.replace(/\S/g, '_').split('')
  let len = string.replace(/ /g, '').length
  let count = len - Math.ceil(len * percent)
  while (count) {
    let int = Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length)
    if (re[int] != ' ' && re[int] == '_') {
      re[int] = string[int]
      count--
    }
  }

  return re.join('')
}

console.log(replace("mystring lorem", 0.8))
console.log(replace("mystring", 0.8))
console.log(replace("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", 0.2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a generic method for approach your needs. It is based on the generation of a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set)
 that will hold an `N%` of the indexes (with random generation) that will be replaced. Then, we use the `replacement` function of [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to check on every iteration if the replacement for a `token` needs to be done, basically checking if the current index of the character to be replaced is on the previous mentioned `Set`.

```js
const replace = (str, token, percentage) =>
{
    // Get the quantity of characters to be replaced.

    var numToReplace = Math.floor(str.length * percentage);

    // Generate a set of random indexes to be replaced.

    var idxsToReplace = new Set();

    while (idxsToReplace.size < numToReplace)
    {
        idxsToReplace.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length));
    }

    // Do the replacement of characters:

    return str.replace(/./g, (x, offset) => idxsToReplace.has(offset) ? token : x);
}

console.log(replace("mystring", "_", 0.8));
console.log(replace("mystring", "+", 0.5));
console.log(replace("Hello World", "#", 0.7));
```